# create shape from an arbitrary closed loop on a 3d object

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm currently building a 3D communications tool in three.js where people can highlight any area of a 3d object and comment on it.
The user should be able to draw a closed loop on the surface of a 3d object and the software will highlight the enclosed area.
I need to store this shape somehow and be able to detect it when a user clicks it again.

For example, the user might draw this:
[image]

I then need to figure out this enclosing shape:
[image]

Currently, I'm thinking of storing the loop as many line segments, and then calculating whether a user has clicking inside the shape by using some raycasting algorithm.
But I have no idea if this is efficient or how the raycasting will work.
Is there a more efficient algorithm or procedure out there?

Comment: Raycasting should be fast if you combine it with a tree structure like the AABB tree. Storing the loop as many line segments sounds reasonable. You should also find the polygons enclosed by the loop so the raycasting will hit them. You have to decide whther the shape keeps the list of enclosed polygons or the other way around.